# Solving Dense-dot-Sparse

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have sparse matrix `S`:

```
<14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

and dense vector `d`:

```
Out[7]: (1, 14940)
```

and would like to compute `d dot S`, with expected dimensions `1 x 14940`. Due to the dimensions, this should work out. However, `np.dot` does not understand the types of its arguments, and hence

```
np.dot(d, S)
```

leads to a crash. Next,

```
d.dot(S)
```

weirdly leads to

```
Out[4]: 
array([[<14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
        <14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
        <14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
        ...,
        <14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
        <14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
        <14940x14940 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39840 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]], dtype=object)
```

My final attempt was to use `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.dot`, but it apparently expects both arguments to be sparse:

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.dot(d, S)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-3363ca62dfea>", line 1, in <module>
    scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.dot(d, S)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py", line 362, in dot
    return self.matvec(x)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'matvec'
```

How can I compute the dot product?

Comment: Can't you just convert the vector to a sparse encoding then?

Comment: There are "todense" functions for different types of scipy sparse matrices, you can use that too. Seems you need both in the same format.

Comment: @jdehesa please, garbage-collect me now... Head->Desk.

Comment: Btw I suppose converting your matrix to CSC format would be better for the operation you want to do...

Answer (score 2):

Use `d*S`, where the sparse interpretation of `*` applies.

```
In [198]: S = sparse.random(10,10,.2)
In [199]: d = np.arange(10)[None,:]
In [200]: np.dot(d,S)
Out[200]: 
array([[<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
    ...
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]], dtype=object)
```

is produced because `np.dot` naively tries to makes `S` dense with:

```
In [201]: np.array(S)
Out[201]: 
array(<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in COOrdinate format>, dtype=object)
```

The correct way to make `S` dense is with its own `.toarray` method, or the short `.A` property:

```
In [202]: np.dot(d, S.A)
Out[202]: 
array([[ 0.14692294,  0.        ,  6.11562384, 10.33950994,  4.96106786,
         3.45833981, 10.40602568,  7.14361287,  9.92141019,  0.        ]])
```

Using the `*` operator does the same thing.  For sparse matrix `*` is matrix multiplication.

```
In [203]: d*S
Out[203]: 
array([[ 0.14692294,  0.        ,  6.11562384, 10.33950994,  4.96106786,
         3.45833981, 10.40602568,  7.14361287,  9.92141019,  0.        ]])
```

---

We can also make `d` sparse

```
In [204]: D = sparse.csr_matrix(d)
In [205]: D*S
Out[205]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [206]: _.A
Out[206]: 
array([[ 0.14692294,  0.        ,  6.11562384, 10.33950994,  4.96106786,
         3.45833981, 10.40602568,  7.14361287,  9.92141019,  0.        ]])
```

(this sparse sparse matrix product is actually a bit slower.)

With both sparse `np.dot` behaves:

```
In [208]: np.dot(D,S).A
Out[208]: 
array([[ 0.14692294,  0.        ,  6.11562384, 10.33950994,  4.96106786,
         3.45833981, 10.40602568,  7.14361287,  9.92141019,  0.        ]])
```

THe newer `matmul` operator also works (but notice the dimensions, (1,n)):

```
In [209]: d@S
Out[209]: 
array([[ 0.14692294,  0.        ,  6.11562384, 10.33950994,  4.96106786,
         3.45833981, 10.40602568,  7.14361287,  9.92141019,  0.        ]])
```